# Compare same column in different tables Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables where I'm trying to match records and output the records that do not match.

- Table A is a production table that holds `name`, `upc`. (Has a Model)
- Table B is an imported Excel sheet that holds `name` and `upc` (No Model, only the table)
- Table A has 986 rows
- Table B has 991 rows

> The main goal is to get the missing rows from Table B and Add them to
> Table A.

I would also like to get the following information:

1. Number of matching `upc` from table A & Table B
2. Number of Not matching `upc` from table A & Table B
3. Output the unmatched `name` & `upc`

How would I achieve this?

For #1 I tried:

```
use \App\Models\A;

$matchingUpc = A::join('b', 'b.upc', '=', 'a.upc')->count();

dd($matchingUpc); // = 990 ???
```

This outputs the count of 990 which does not make sense because Table A only has 986 rows.

I know I'm probably making this much harder than it is.
Any help or a point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the 4 extra records are upcs that are duped?

Comment: Ah good call. I didn't think about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [Where Exists Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-exists-clauses)

The whereExists method allows you to write "where exists" SQL clauses. The whereExists method accepts a closure which will receive a query builder instance, allowing you to define the query that should be placed inside of the "exists" clause:

```
 $upcMatching  = DB::table('production')
            ->whereExists(function ($query) {
                $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                    ->from('imported')
                    ->whereColumn('production.upc', 'imported.upc');
            })->count();
      

        $upcNotMatching = DB::table('production')
            ->whereNotExists(function ($query) {
                $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                    ->from('imported')
                    ->whereColumn('production.upc', 'imported.upc');
            })->get();


 $numberOfUnMatchedCount=DB::table('production')->count('upc')-$upcMatching;

//or simply:

$numberOfUnMatchedCount= $upcNotMatching->count();
```